# How to understand two tensors's dot multiplication in tensorflow?

Tags: matrix, tensorflow, deep-learning

the code :

```
y*tf.ones([x_shapes[0], x_shapes[1], x_shapes[2] , y_shapes[3]])
```

y is a tensor which dimension is [64 , 1 , 1 , 10]
x is a tensor which dimension is [64 , 28 ,28 , 1]

tf.ones([x_shapes[0], x_shapes[1], x_shapes[2] , y_shapes[3]])

will generate a tensor which dimension is [64 , 28 , 28 , 10]

so ,how to understand the dot product of two tensors which have different dimensions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is element-wise multiplication where two tensors are first made the same size using numpy's [broadcasting rules](https://scipy.github.io/old-wiki/pages/EricsBroadcastingDoc)